# Site for questions about networking in the course of developing a distributed application

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a dedicated site which focuses on networking solutions?

I need to set up my application in a distributed environment and make sure all requests are sent via a given list of servers. This requires lot of activities related to networking, about which I hardly know anything.

Comment: There is the Network Engineering SE Site: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ although I don't know if this topic is considered on-topic for that site.

Comment: @{whoever VTCed as off-topic -> programming} No. Wrong. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @michaelb958 I nearly flagged this as a programming question, but then read the last two sentences properly. Learn More, is it possible to change the title so that it's clear from the get go that you're looking for a site that focuses on networking solutions?

Comment: @DennisMeng So nearly did I.

Comment: I gave a different title. Somebody edited.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that https://serverfault.com/ would be the best site for you to ask those types of network questions on.  With that said, please read this page https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic before asking a question on there.

What can you ask about there?

> ```
> Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software.
> Business/Enterprise grade virtualization
> Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
> Network routing, switches, and firewalls
> Operations, maintenance, and monitoring
> ```

Sly mentioned in a comment that https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be the right place. Which, I'm not sure if it is either. But check out this page https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see if that would fit your type of questions. Based on the small amount of information you gave, I would think ServerFault would probably be the better choice.